# Ruby, array of hashes convert to 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes.

```
arr =[{:code=>"404", :demo => "1"}, {:code=>"302", :demo => "1"}, {:code=>"200", :demo => "1"}]
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
[["404", "1"], ["302", "1"], ["200", "1"]]
```

I tried:

```
arr.each do |a|
 puts a.values
end
```

But this create only 1 array as;

```
["404", "1", "302", "1", "200", "1"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arr.map(&:values)
#⇒ [["404", "1"], ["302", "1"], ["200", "1"]]
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann I see. Downvoted the question and voted to close.

Comment: @StefanPochmann somebody trains an AI bot? :)

Comment: Then I hope the training takes the vote/close feedback into account (I don't know much about AI and its training, I assume that's how it works :-)